# LPR on a Brother PT-P900 printer "Incompatible tape" with 12mm label

Tags: printing, brother

The printer Brother PT-P900W does not print in linux with the Tape 12mm. It prints without problem with the tape 32mm. The error shown in the printer is "Incompatible tape".

Strange thing: on Windows it prints without any problems with both tapes.

Any idea on how to select the correct type in the lpr command on Linux?

Thank you.

Here  the commands (with text, pdf, and png) that I've tried until now without any success:

```
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lpr -P PT-P900 -o PageSize=12x20 test.txt 
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lpr -P PT-P900 -o PageSize=12x20 test.txt 
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lpr -P PT-P900 -o PageSize=12x20 -o BrPriority=BrQuality test.txt 
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lsusb
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lpr -P PT-P900 -o PageSize=12x12 -o BrPriority=BrQuality test.txt 
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lpr -P PT-P900 -o PageSize=12x12 -o BrPriority=BrQuality back-label.png 
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lp -p PT-P900 -o media=Custom.12x12mm back-label.png 
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lp -P PT-P900 -o media=Custom.12x12mm back-label.png 
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lp -d PT-P900 -o media=Custom.12x12mm back-label.png 
request id is PT-P900-32 (1 file(s))
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lp -d PT-P900 test.txt 
request id is PT-P900-33 (1 file(s))
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lp -d PT-P900 back-label.png 
request id is PT-P900-34 (1 file(s))
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lp -d PT-P900 back-label.png 
request id is PT-P900-35 (1 file(s))
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lp -d PT-P900 -o media=Custom.12x12mm back-label.png 
request id is PT-P900-36 (1 file(s))
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lp -d PT-P900 -o orientation-requested=4 test.txt 
request id is PT-P900-37 (1 file(s))
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lp -d PT-P900 -o orientation-requested=4 back-label.png request id is PT-P900-38 (1 file(s))
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lp -d PT-P900 -o scaling=50 back-label.png 
request id is PT-P900-39 (1 file(s))
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lp -d PT-P900 -o media=Custom.12x12mm back-label.png.pdf 
request id is PT-P900-40 (1 file(s))
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lp -d PT-P900 -o media=Custom.12x12mm back-label.png.pdf 
request id is PT-P900-41 (1 file(s))
simone@simone-VirtualBox:~/Programs/qrcode-labels$ lp -d PT-P900 -o scaling=50 back-label.png request id is PT-P900-42 (1 file(s))
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have some installing to do. I wasnt able to find the specific LPR command, but it does look like you can access tape size by installing the Brother driver for linux [Brother Linux utility/Drivers](https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqendbranchprintable.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=lptd4100neuk&faqid=faqp00100414_000&printable=true)

Just do a CTRL+F and search tape in the page and you will see how to implement the option.

From the page: "The supported media length for continuous tape is about 100 mm.
Use the paper tool command to add a custom media size longer/shorter than 100mm.
For more information, see "Adding a custom media size for continuous tape (Linux)"."